# Как настроить ServerAlias

Tags: apache, redirect

Есть 2 домена. На одном - лендинг, на втором лендинг+сайт внутри.
Нужно что бы при заходе на домен2  сначала отображался лендинг(то есть главная), а далее по ссылке будет переход на внутреннюю сайта домен1.

Как сделать при помощи ServerAlias чтобы переадресация была только внутренних линков. То есть всего что после домен2.ком/****

в данный момент конфиг примерно такой

```
<VirtualHost домен1.local:80>

DocumentRoot    "\domains\lifedating.local\web"
ServerName      "lifedating.local"
ServerAlias     "lifedating.local/*" testdating.local/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильный конфиг апача прибл. такой:

`<VirtualHost lifedating.local:80>
DocumentRoot    "/www/domains/lifedating.local/web"
ServerName      lifedating.local
ServerAlias     testdating.local`

В `DocumentRoot`  указывать пут от корня. В виндовс - от диска.

Потом обычный редирект в хтацессе.